# Naming a new file in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I just started learning python. Up until now, I primarly worked with jupyter notebooks, but now wanted to try out some IDEs. So I tried out PyCharm.

So I started creating some files in a project and started trying out the commands and stuff and there is one thing which just drives me crazy, cause I can not seem to find an answer.

Everytime I create a new python file and name it something like "simple_message", it just saves as a normal file and I can't run any code in it. As soon as I remove the underscore, the file convention changes to an actual python file and I can run the code written in it. So I thought it might be the underscore that makes trouble, so I tried creating other files with underscores but all of them worked. Can someone enlighten me, why does the file name "simple_message" not work as a python file?

Thank you!

[From this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcCIq.png) [To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpYb0.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding .py extension when saving using underscore?

Comment: What PyCharm version are you using? That could be important too...

Comment: I tried to name a file as simple_message.py by using PyCharm and it worked. Please uninstall PyCharm and then re-install it to see if it will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently PyCharm context menu lets you choose the file type to create.
If you choose "file" you MUST provide the extension .py
If You choose "Python File" pycharm handles the extension for You.

[image: Right click on the pycharm projects tab]

Answer (score 2):

For me I have to right click on a directory (folder) and select "New" → "Python File" to make a python file. If I go "New" → "File" it will create a text document. So long as you click the correct option you shouldn't have to worry about typing the '.py' or '.txt'

Alternatively I can right click and select "New" → "File" and then name it "simple_message.py" and it will save as a python file correctly, but I must include the .py using this method

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But when I create a new python file and name it simple_message it still shows as an text file. As soon as I delete the the underscore it converts into the python file, like it should be.

Comment: @n_urb How does it show as a regular text file? Perhaps you could include a screenshot? Does it run if you select the tab that opens, toss in a `import os` or something, and press Ctrl + Shift + F10 (all at the same time)?

Comment: I added screenshots in OP. First one is file name with underscore, where I can't run anything, second is without underscore where I can run the code.

Comment: @n_urb and with your `message_simple.py` did you experience the error? Or only with the `simple_message.py` version?

Comment: Yeah haha. message_simple.py is working. I might just reinstall and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to right click in the text of your .py file and manually choose run from the menu.

Pycharm doesn’t automatically reindex when you create a new .py file, and so it probably just doesn’t know what you want it to run when you hit the green play button.

If you’re saying your python interpreter won’t run a .py file because it has an underscore in the name, that’s just not possible unless you have a modded interpreter or have done something really strange to your OS and I’m guessing you haven’t done either.

Update: it sounds like you don’t have the .py file extension on your file. This will not run for reasons that have nothing to do with Pycharm. Pycharm may “bridge the gap” for you automatically in some situations, but no reason to rely on that.

Comment: I can't run the file, as it is treated as a text file. As soon as I rename that exact file and just get rid of the underscore, it automatically converts into a python file and I can run the whole thing. As soon as I rename it again and add the underscore, it converts into the text file again. Pretty weird..

Comment: Add the .py extension

Comment: I have added screenshots in the OP. As you can see, I have the .py file extension, but it is still treated as a txt file. Or do you mean something different with .py file extension. Take a look at my screens.

Comment: How are you “running” it?

Comment: Well, usually by pressing ctrl+r. But like I said, my only problem is, why the file I created is not treated as a python file as soon as I add this damn underscore haha.

Comment: Try right clicking the text of your file after editing the name, then clicking run. Are you getting an error message of any kind?